# Push notifications for android, questions

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, push

Hello i new developer in android, my question is :

which are the platforms that exist?

I read to C2DM and Google Cloud Messaging

which is the best?

Exists more?

in which users do not have to register to use in application?

in which work in web service, based in json from project in ruby on rails?

My questions are to decide with which will working for  project.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Messaging [is the replacement for C2DM.](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html) There are other services like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/), [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) and [PubNub](http://pubnub.com) which offer features like push and more.

Comment: Try https://pushy.me/